# Set value by default in first position in index array

Tags: c++

Im trying set an array to have always same value in first position, but idk how to do that. for example array[10] always array[0] = 100, then continue add ohters number like: array[100,1,2,3.....], loop array[100,1,2,3.....] etc.

```
int main() {


    int arrayNumber[10];
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            arrayNumber[0] = 100;
            printf("%d\n", arrayNumber[i]);
            Sleep(100);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the purpose?

Comment: my array should have always same value in first position array[0]= 100

Comment: Still don't understand. You have only one array, what does "have always same value in first position" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the first value outside the loop and start the loop at 1.

```
arrayNumber[0] = 100;
for (int i = 1; i < arraysize; i++)
{
    arrayNumber[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
  int arrayNumber[10] = {100};
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    arrayNumber[i] = i;
  }
}
```

The first operator above declares the array and initializes the first it's element with the value 100, then the loop fills other elements with 1, 2, 3, ..., 9.

Since your asked about C++ let introduce C++-like solution below.

```
#include <numeric>
int main() {
  int arrayNumber[10] = {100};
  std::iota(arrayNumber + 1, arrayNumber + 10, 1);
}
```

Here the function `iota` fills the passed range in the array with sequentially increasing values, starting with 1.

Comment: Good call on `iota`.